# gmail users.watch API 400 Bad Request using domain wide delegation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-functions, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Getting 400 Bad Request when calling users.watch Gmail API from GCP Cloud Function

I'm trying to automate the call to watch() on a users GSuite email account. I have already given domain-wide access to the default service account of the Cloud Function by following the steps outlined in the link below

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guids/delegation

I have authorized the following scopes:
`profile,email, https://mail.google.com/,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly`

Deployed Cloud Function code:

```
exports.watchEmail = async () => {
  console.info('authenticating');

  const auth = await google.auth.getClient({
    scopes: ['profile',
      'email',
      'https://mail.google.com/',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'],
  });

  console.info('<-- authenticated');

  console.info('watch on email', 'no-reply@telico.ca');
  const api = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth });
  const response = await api.users.watch({
    userId: '<USER_EMAIL>',
    requestBody: {
      topicName: 'projects/<PROJECT_ID>/topics/processEmail',
      labelIds: ["INBOX"]
    }
  });
  console.info('<-- watch on file', JSON.stringify(response));
};
```

When executing the CloudFunction, I am seeing `Error: Bad Request at Gaxios.request` printed in the logs.

Comment: First item. Remove those changes to the default service account. Depending on which default account you changed, every instance will have those permissions. Create a new service account, assign Domain Wide Delegation and assign that service account to the function. Next, you assigned too many scopes to the service account. Figure out which one you need and only use that one. You basically gave everyone permission to impersonate, read, send and delete everyone's email in G Suite.